The PDF file size I generate with Puppeteer is large
I am generating pdf using puppeteersharp, which is the .NET port of puppeteer. At first, my file size was a serious 7.5mb. I wrote a compress method using ghostscript to reduce this size further, but my file size decreased to 4.1mb.
How can I reduce the size more than compressing the media elements in the PDF?
public async Task<BaseResponse> GetPdf(string outputFile)
{
    await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();
    using (var browser = await PuppeteerSharp.Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true
    }))
    using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
    {
        await page.GoToAsync("http://localhost:3000/");
        var html = page.GetContentAsync();
        await page.PdfAsync(outputFile, new PdfOptions
        { 
            Format = PaperFormat.A4,
            DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
            PrintBackground = true,
            MarginOptions = new MarginOptions
            {
                Top = "10mm",
                Bottom = "10mm",
                Left = "10mm",
                Right = "10mm"
            }
        });
    }
    string coutput = "compressed_" + outputFile;
    CompressPdf(outputFile, coutput);

    byte[] pdfBytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(coutput);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);

    return new BaseResponse { Successful = true, MemoryStream = memoryStream };
}

I also tried launching headless  using HeadlessMode = HeadlessMode.Shell
 public static void CompressPdf(string inputFile, string outputFile)
 {
     var gsPath = @"C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.03.1\bin\gswin64.exe";
     var args = $"-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile={outputFile} {inputFile}";

     var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
     {
         StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
         {
             FileName = gsPath,
             Arguments = args,
             RedirectStandardOutput = true,
             UseShellExecute = false,
             CreateNoWindow = true
         }
     };

     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
 }

kind regards

How much content is there, in bytes, before trying to convert to pdf?
